# STRICT MODE -> Changed controller structure, getting 'key is not defined' at a For In loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I had an Angular project that I refactored with the McFly angular generator, and now I have a function using a for, in loop that is not working where it was before. I get an error that key is not defined.

Here's the function:

```
   $scope.findAnswerColorDiff = function(){
        var choice, differenceBetween, choice2
        for (key in $scope.profileCompare){
            if ($scope.profileCompare.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.currentUser.You.questionAnswer.length; i++){
                    if ($scope.currentUser.You.questionAnswer[i] == true){
                        choice = i;
                        console.log(choice);
                    }
                }
                for (var i = 0 ; i < $scope.profileCompare[key].questionAnswer.length; i++){
                    if ($scope.profileCompare[key].questionAnswer[i] == true){
                        choice2 = i;
                        differenceBetween = 0;
                    }
                }
                if (choice2 == choice) {
                    $scope.profileCompare[key].difference = "_0pcnt";
                    console.log("Difference for " + key
                     + " is " + $scope.profileCompare[key].difference);
                } else if (choice2 < choice) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
                        choice2++
                        differenceBetween++
                        if(choice2==choice){
                            $scope.setColorDifference(differenceBetween) 
                            break 
                        }
                    }
                } else if (choice < choice2) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
                        choice++
                        differenceBetween++
                        if(choice2==choice){
                            $scope.setColorDifference(differenceBetween)
                            break 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Here's the object it should be iterating through:

```
    $scope.profileCompare = {

        Pizza: {
            name: "Pizza",
            questionAnswer: [false, false, false, false, false, true],
            questionImportance: "Important",
            difference: undefined,
            office: "Cheese",
            index: undefined
        },
        GreenieBigNameGuy: {
            name: "Greenie Centipede",
            questionAnswer: [false, false, false, false, true, false],
            questionImportance: "Very Important",
            difference: undefined,
            office: "Green Beans",
            index: undefined
        },
        Red: {
            name: "Seeing Red",
            questionAnswer: [false, false, false, true, false, false],
            questionImportance: "Not Important",
            difference: undefined,
            office: "milk",
            index: undefined
        },
        Yellow: {
            name: "Christmas Tree",
            questionAnswer: [false, false, true, false, false, false],
            questionImportance: "Not Important",
            difference: undefined,
            office: "Elf",
            index: undefined
        },
```

Where did this come from? It was working perfectly before, and still is in the old project.

Here's the new controller structure. All the logic is underneath the activate() function:

```
var controllername = 'questionsCtrl';

module.exports = function(app) {
var fullname = app.name + '.' + controllername;
/*jshint validthis: true */

var deps = ['$scope', '$rootScope'];

function controller(scope, rootScope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.controllername = fullname;

    var activate = function() {
    };
    activate();
    console.log("inside questionsCtrl");

}

controller.$inject = deps;
app.controller(fullname, controller);
};
```

Here is the old controller logic:

```
app.controller('ComparisonCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams) {
console.log("Inside ComparisonCtrl");
....logic here...
});
```

Here's the complete list of errors:

```
ReferenceError: key is not defined
at Scope.module.exports.$scope.findAnswerColorDiff (http://localhost:5000/scripts/bundle.js:33167:18)
at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5000/scripts/bundle.js:17603:15), <anonymous>:4:248)
at ngEventDirectives.(anonymous function).compile.element.on.callback (http://localhost:5000/scripts/bundle.js:27783:17)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:5000/scripts/bundle.js:20288:28)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:5000/scripts/bundle.js:20388:25)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:5000/scripts/bundle.js:27788:23)
at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (http://localhost:5000/scripts/bundle.js:7665:21)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12416$get @ angular.js:9203$get.Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16021(anonymous function) @ angular.js:23416eventHandler @ angular.js:3293
```

Comment: Well, `key` is indeed not defined in `$scope.findAnswerColorDiff`... Try adding it to the list of `var`s in the previous line...

Comment: ...It's a for, in loop. This same code works when in the old file format. Adding it to the list of vars does nothing, you still get the same error.

Comment: :) Glad it's working now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with further research, the problem is with Strict mode. This prevents global variables like an undeclared key like so - `for (key in thing)`.

At first, I took this out of the file, so did not think this was the problem. However, Gulp concatenates all the files with the `gulp browser sync` command. So strict mode was getting through nonetheless.

The workaround, was to do `for (var key in thing)`, which at first appeared not to work. It was breaking the second function, `setColorDiff()`, which couldn't tell what the key was as key was no longer in global scope. To fix this, I added a second parameter for the key to this function.

Now working hunky dori